# How to give permission to a directory which including lots of images

Tags: permissions

I want to run my project on localhost and i gave permission to all directories including in my project.
 But the problem is in Image directory. how can i give permission to each and every images. it is quit difficult for me because there is lots of images in my image folder. 
I used **sudo chmod 777 < directory>**

Comment: yeah its working.

Comment: Setting permissions to 777 for **image files** is a **bad idea**. What are you trying to do?

Comment: No! not 777! You want 640!

Comment: Or `644`. Preferably the entire directory should be group-owned by `www-data` and given `g+r`.

Comment: m trying to run my project on localhost.. i give the permission because it is not showing the proper design .

Answer (score 1):

This is an **evil** trick that I some times use if I am lazy about changing permissions.

1. **[Cautionary]** Disconnect the internet to prevent shenanigans from rogue elements.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open up a terminal.
3. `sudo nautilus`
4. Navigate to your pictures directory.
5. Select the files you want to change permissions of
6. Right-click to Properties.
7. Goto Permissions Tab.
8. Do your ghastly deed.
9. Exit Nautilus.
10. Reconnect internet.

Remember; this is **evil**, because you are giving a file manager incredible power.